# Screen flickering through HDMI on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nvidia, hdmi, external-monitor

I am having problems connecting external monitors through HDMI. The screen is flickering horribly, going on and off (no signal) unexpectedly, sometimes just stays blank. I am using the recommended nvidia-driver-390 for my graphics card. My notebook si HP ProBook 470 G4. Output from some diagnostics I have done:

**sudo lshw -c video**

```
  *-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 02
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: iomemory:1f0-1ef iomemory:1f0-1ef irq:128 memory:1ff0000000-1ff0ffffff memory:1fe0000000-1fefffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
*-display
   description: 3D controller
   product: GM108M [GeForce 930MX]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a2
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   resources: irq:129 memory:d2000000-d2ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128)
```

**xrandr**

```
HDMI-1-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x576i      50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

I also found some interesting messages in my syslog

```
Aug  4 07:46:39 podlomar-HP-ProBook-470-G4 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1175]: (--) modeset(G0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 300000KHz
Aug  4 07:46:39 podlomar-HP-ProBook-470-G4 gnome-control-c[1830]: Config not applicable: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: The requested configuration is based on stale information
Aug  4 07:46:39 podlomar-HP-ProBook-470-G4 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1175]: (--) modeset(G0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 300000KHz
Aug  4 07:47:41 podlomar-HP-ProBook-470-G4 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1175]: (--) modeset(G0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 300000KHz
Aug  4 07:47:41 podlomar-HP-ProBook-470-G4 gnome-control-c[1830]: Config not applicable: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: The requested configuration is based on stale information
Aug  4 07:47:41 podlomar-HP-ProBook-470-G4 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1175]: (--) modeset(G0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 300000KHz
```

But I don't know what they mean. I already tried different resolutions and frequencies in xrandr but nothing works. Either the display flickers or shows no signal at all. I tested two monitors, one is BenQ 24" FullHD (shown in logs), the other one is 32" WQHD display. All behave the same. I used two different HDMI cables with no difference.

Comment: I have a similar issue with an Asus that has shared graphics.  The problem already occurred on Windows 10 (dual booted) and only started happening when I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04.  Tracking this question as I would love to have a solution.